# Mongoose Cast to Number failed for value "{ ip: 78 }" at path "ip"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have created a schema to saved an ip adress. When saving my model mongoose returns me:

> ip: Cast to Number failed for value "{ ip: 78 }" at path "ip"

But my number is an integer, so it should work well.

Here my schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema= mongoose.Schema;

var ChatSchema = new Schema({    
    // _id:ObjectId,
    ip:{required:true, type: Number},
    message: {required:true, type: Array},
    room: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Chat", ChatSchema)
```

Here my socketEmit snippet:

```
this.socket.emit("join", {
    ip: Math.round(Math.random() *100)
}
```

Here my server.js to save my data on mongoose:

```
 if(ChatScanValue === undefined){ 
        console.log("!Chat.find(ip)")
        var prospectChat= new Chat({ip, message:["empty_chat"]})
        console.log("prospectChat: ", prospectChat)
        prospectChat.save((err, chatData) => { 
            if(err) throw err; 
            console.log("chat object created.")
 })
```

Why it fails? I can't figure it out, I have tried to play a few with  the object passed in Chat, change the value of `ip`, change  the schemaType in my mongoose's model. I'm stilling seeking for the reason of the bugg.

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: where are you assigning the `ip` variable? My guess is that it isn't the number but an object containing an `ip` property

Comment: yes it's an object containing the ip property as following : `{ip: value}`, the object is emited from client to the "join" event in my socket, then the processing that I have reproduced on my post occurs. So that it and I expect that when I pass my ip object to my mongoose schema it should so assign automatically to the field `ip` with the value `ip.ip` ? hence the `ip` passed directly in the fields's space like reproduced: `new Chat({ip, message:["empty_chat"]})`

Comment: What happens if you create the new chat with `new Chat({ ip: ip.ip, ... })` directly? I'm not sure the schema will pull out the fields as you're implying

Comment: yes I have tried your appreciable idea and it returns: `Cannot destructure property `ip` of 'undefined' or 'null'`, I'm trying to understand why currently

Comment: I think it's a codeflow problem

Comment: that was effectively a coding's flow problem and to precise `ip.ip` had supported the process, work well now.